# creating / deleting sections using the PeNet library

Tags: c#, portable-executable

I am using the [PeNet nuget package](https://github.com.cnpmjs.org/secana/PeNet) to work with a pe file, there was a problem when creating or deleting a section, I take the code from the author's [example](http://secana.github.io/PeNet/articles/sections.html), but nothing works. (No errors appear, but no files are written/overwritten.)

Using a C # console application, here's the code:

```
var bin = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\test.dll");
var peFile = new PeNet.PeFile(bin);

peFile.AddSection(".newSec", 100, (ScnCharacteristicsType)0x40000040);
peFile.RemoveSection(".rsrc", true);
```

Comment: kind person, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/secana/PeNet/issues/34) about a similar topic:

> PeNet works internally by loading the whole PE file into a buffer. All changes you make are done to this buffer in memory. If you want to save your changes, you just have to save the buffer.

Unfortunately, the code offered there is incorrect. PEFile has no `Buff` property. So use:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(
    "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\newDLL.dll", 
    peFile.RawFile.ToArray()
);
```

Sadly, it seems the author never implemented the `Save` method either...

#### Further Reading from the docs:

- [PeFile.RawFile](http://secana.github.io/PeNet/api/PeNet.PeFile.html#PeNet_PeFile_RawFile)
- [IRawFile.ToArray](http://secana.github.io/PeNet/api/PeNet.FileParser.IRawFile.html#PeNet_FileParser_IRawFile_ToArray)

Comment: thanks, it helped.
is it possible to contact you somehow?

Comment: @margelov Do you have a quick follow-on question? If so, you can comment here, or I could create a chat for this if you think it will take additional discussion. I'm not an expert on this library, though. Depending on how complicated the issue is, you may want to ask a separate question instead.

Comment: maybe you know a more convenient library for working with pe-files?

Comment: @margelov I don't think there is one (from searching around anyway), but it looks like the last update to the package was fairly recent. Perhaps opening an issue on GitHub would be your best course of action if you want additional functionality.